# How to pass 2 dates in .Where?

Tags: c#, linq

currently in the code I am outputting the employees table which have end dates of anything from before today's date and up to 90 days. I am trying to make it so only employees with maximum -30 days and + 90 of today's date. 
(Fairly new so be easy)
(NOT SURE HOW TO CORRECTLY USE 2 DATES FOR .ADDDAYS ) 
Thanks

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var employees = db.employees;
        var today = DateTime.Today.AddDays(90);
        var past = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30);

        var q = db.employees.Where(t => t.EndDate <= today );

        return View(q.OrderByDescending(t => t.EndDate));

    }
```

Comment: Try using two conditions with `&&` operator: `var q = db.employees.Where(t => t.EndDate >= past && t.EndDate <= today );`.

Comment: Shouldn't the question title be "How to pass 2 dates in .Where()"? If so, please edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Why can't you use a `AND (&&)` condition like

```
var q = db.employees.Where(t => t.EndDate <= today && t.EndDate >= past);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simple by using conditional-AND `&&` operator & combining both queries as single line:

```
var q = db.employees.Where(t => t.EndDate >= past && t.EndDate <= today)
                    .OrderByDescending(t => t.EndDate);

return View(q);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code. You can add the `OrderByDescending(t => t.EndDate)` on the first line of code.

```
var q = db.employees.Where(t => t.EndDate >= past && t.EndDate<= today)OrderByDescending(t => t.EndDate);
return view(q);
```